# Timeout in the close review queue when filtering by tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

I set the tag filter on the close review queue on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) to `ocamllex`. (YES! Finally the close review queue is usable.) All I see is the “loading item” message for a while, then a popup tells me

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

This happens both with Firefox 15 and Chrome 21.

The tag has no question with pending close votes, and probably none with pending close flags. I get the same behavior with the `ocaml` tag, which does have questions with pending close votes, but probably none that I haven't reviewed already. I do get the expected questions when I set the filter to `haskell`, which has questions for me to review. I get the impression that the response from the server is slower to come with `haskell` as with `c`, but that may be purely subjective or due to network jitter.

I've been getting timeouts with the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag a lot, though without a pop-up. And I know that tag's close queue is nowhere near empty.

Comment: These timeouts used to occur whenever you loaded the "all" option of the old review queue, except it didn't give you a nice error message. It just gave a generic HTTP error saying the server didn't respond in time.

Comment: per my [recent testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773 "some results reported here") of close votes queue, timeouts appear to depend on tag popularity. I have been getting 15-20-30 seconds delays with low traffic [tag:java-me] as opposed to 1-2 seconds with much more popular [tag:java].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

Our SQL query plan was blazing fast for popular tags, but unusably slow for more obscure tags like `ocamllex`. Sorry about that.