# Is it normal to wait 10 seconds after reviewing a post when the posts are being filtered?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timeout in the close review queue when filtering by tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152043/timeout-in-the-close-review-queue-when-filtering-by-tags)

I am reviewing some questions on the review queue (vote to close), and I noticed I wait at least 10 seconds before being able to see the next question, after I reviewed a question. I am reviewing the questions filtering them by the used tags ([drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal)), and there are questions voted to be closed using that tag.

[image: screenshot]

Without filtering by tag, the delay before seeing the next question is less than half second.

[image: screenshot]

Is a 10-second delay normal, or is too much?

Comment: potentially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152043/172958

Comment: As @Kevin says, most likely server side issue probably the current queries are too "heavy". Maybe they work on the live data by mistake rather then on the cached data..

Comment: This question is different: I am reviewing questions voted to be closed, and which are using that tag.