# Tag-filtered close review queue times out

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, vote-to-close

I'm reviewing close votes, filtered by tag [android](/questions/tagged/android).

At some point in the review queue, I cannot proceed to the next review. After completing a review, I get

> An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again.

Reloading the page shows that the review went through:

> You have already reviewed this item.

Clicking on Next times out with

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

Retrying does not help. I can continue reviewing only the following ways:

- Reset the filter and review other questions in the queue.
- Wait for some time for new reviews to appear in the queue. Reviewing will get stuck the same way after a while.

I have experienced this problem for a few days now, the same problem every day.

I suspect there's a database query that is taking way too long to complete.

Here's a screenshot with Chrome Network trace. This particular review is not a problem. Loading the next review does not work.

[image: Screenshot with Chrome]

Related issues:

- [Timeout in the close review queue when filtering by tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152043/timeout-in-the-close-review-queue-when-filtering-by-tags)

---

Edit 10-Nov-2013: Now I'm able to go deep down in the tag-filtered close review queue without seeing this timeout. Might be related to the recent Stack Exchange database server upgrade, who knows. Let's see if this issue is still seen on busier days than this Sunday.

---

Edit 15-Nov-2013: Not reproducible anymore. Been able to review ancient close reviews from 1..2 years back without seeing timeouts. Suggest setting to [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: I cannot find a corresponding stack trace. Can you provide a link with the review that went wrong?

Comment: @Sklivvz Done my 40 reviews today, will see tomorrow if/when this issue reproduces.

Comment: @Sklivvz No specific review going wrong, loading the next one fails. Updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3088106

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes I can see that URL in the screenshot address bar. Loading that particular review was not the problem. Loading the next review with my filters and already reviewed/skipped reviews didn't succeed.

Comment: I think not everyone has to retype the link again, so I added it as comment. No offense, but links are easier to use than an url embedded in an immage.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Ok, didn't understand first why you posted that as a comment as it is not relevant to the problem, really. (I could have made it more clear in the question but cannot edit now as tags are broken on mSO).