# Why my this question has been closed when there are many like it at SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, broken-windows

There are hundreds of questions regarding make [my code DRY](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DRY%20How%20Code) in SO. I don't know why my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452869/how-to-make-this-javascript-snippet-dry-dont-repeat-yourself) has been closed?

Comment: "There are hundreds of cars speeding so I don't know why I've been given a speeding ticket"

Comment: @AakashM, then why not you closed the hundred of other similar questions. Is this question is off-topic? This is regarding programming.

Comment: I'm not sure who you're addressing with that "you". I am merely pointing out that the existence of successful rule-breakers does not mean that no rule-breaking should be addressed.

Comment: It's a poor question. It basically states: "This is my code, now you make it better." It shows zero-effort. Perhaps (as commented) the Code Review SE would be a slightly better venue, but even there I don't think it would be a great question. (Should you take it there, read their FAQ first. I don't participate there so can't recommend anything).

Comment: your question just happened to pop near the top of [Huge Close Votes review queue on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151833/165773) (about 50K questions in queue). Wait for a few months and you'll probably see other makemycodebetter questions get closed, too

Answer (score 10):

Your question post got **closed** because code reviews aren't on topic for SE (there's [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)). It could've also been closed as "[Not a real question](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close)" because you're quite broad in your question.

Your question got **downvoted** because it doesn't show not much research effort. If you tell us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) response will be generally better. One of SE's top users also created a [great checklist for creating good questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), if you follow that it'll most likely get better response as well.

Your question wasn't **migrated**, probably because it was downvoted (i.e. considered low quality): we don't want to send low-quality questions to other communities, that would be a bit rude (IMHO).

**Other questions** may have the same (or *similar*) problems, and may deserve the same treatment, should be judged by the same standard. As pointed out in comments to your meta question: the fact that one (or even a thousand) question "got away with it" doesn't mean a single other question can't be closed/downvoted.

Bottom line: read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), the above linked tips, and improve your question. *After* that you could flag for re-opening or migrating, or in general rest knowing that the questions on SO just got a little better.

Answer (score 2):

Three main points in layman terms.. Rest you read in [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), that is what faq is for.

1. Presence of similar unclosed questions does not mean you can ask
   those kind of questions here. Stackoverflow is a community, where
   like minded people contributes. There are tons of questions gets
   asked here and some of them are bound to get slipped under and stay
   unclosed. That doesn't mean your question will not be closed.
2. Stackoverflow doesn't do work for you. People here are clever enough
   to understand the difference between a *give me codez/do the work
   for me* kind of question and a well researched question. Just adding
   a bit of code in to the question doesn't make it constructive/good.
3. If one of your question gets closed/downvoted, please consider that
   there can be some fault on your (question) side too. It is your (not
   the community's) fault that your questions deemed unfit to the site.
   I am adding this point only because you (a veteran of 166 questions
   in stackoverflow) should have known earlier.