# Reputation should be split according to tags

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, privileges

There are many tags relating to different topics. Suppose a person has answered questions relating to 4 different tags, the reputation must be split as

Tag1 rep =count1+

Tag2 rep =count2+

Tag3 rep =count3+

Tag4 rep =count4+

He must be given authority to cast a vote to close a question which has all these 4 tags (tag 1, tag2, tag3, tag4).

In this way high 'reputation' people who are irrelevant to a particular topic cannot close a question.

This simply prevents reputation misuse.

Comment: So, bad questions can't be closed if the OP chose a broad range of tags that no one has in combination?

Comment: If a person has put such a combination ,then he is intelligent .An intelligent person may not ask a bad question if he doesnt have a bad intention

Comment: So, a smart, malicious spammer can just spam us.

Comment: That's nonsense. Intelligent people are just as capable of asking bad questions as unintelligent people. Asking _good_ questions is almost an art; it's difficult. Having said that it's often easy to identify a "bad"/off-topic etc question. It regularly has nothing to do with the tags the question is being asked in.

Comment: see every other thing has an advantage as well as disadvantage .its only the magnitude variation .The idea what i suggested has more advantage compared to disadvantage .

Comment: @ben is ueqbackwards                                                         some people do not bother for the content of a question .see how can a maths teacher say whats wrong with a science question

Comment: Take all combination of the tags .definitely there would be atleast a single person(higly reputed who knows the gravity of the problem in the question and has intention to help, just not a reputation hunter  ) for every other combination of tags

Comment: What problem does this solve?

Comment: @Ian Questions would be decided as proper questions by proper persons .Prevent unjustified closing of questions.Increase the satisfaction of users who have got answers .More users join the site .More problems can be solved .More ads can be posted That means more revenue

Comment: Closers should have the ability to see the Gravity of problem even in a 'not properly framed question'

Comment: A bad question is a bad question, no matter what subject it concerns.

Comment: That's a list of benefits you that expect from solving the problem, but what is the problem? "unjustified closing of questions" ? All closes are justified, the people that closed it are listed with the reason. The asker is free to modify and improve the question, and in cases where the question was incorrectly closed the asker can ask on meta to have it re-opened. Where is the problem here? This doesn't happen very often. Meta isn't flooded with "why was my Q closed" questions (there's one on the first page atm). And they usually are _not_ re-opened. Indicating that most closures are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Some questions are just not proper questions. Just look at the very next question here on Meta.

[Why my this question has been closed when there are many like it at SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164582/why-my-this-question-has-been-closed-when-there-are-many-like-it-at-so)

It asks why this question was closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452869/how-to-make-this-javascript-snippet-dry-dont-repeat-yourself

which looks like:

> I have the following JavaScript function:
>
> `(lots of code)`
>
> How I can make this DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)?

I don't have any rep in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but I can easily tell that this is not a proper question, because it is not a proper question about *any* language. So the specific tags are not important.