# Frequently closed questions

Tags: feature-request, review, closed-questions, faq-update-request

The close votes review tasks are now 50k+ and rising. There are some frequent patterns, like:

- if your question is *What is the best...?* it is likely to be closed as not constructive
- if your question is *What's wrong with my code?* it is likely to be closed as too localized

Maybe if these patterns would be in FAQ (or even in new users profile), it could lower the review tasks number.

As the comments point out, most of the new users don't read FAQ, just post the question, not caring if it is good or bad, simply hoping for an answer or two, and move away. But SOME users may really want to make the question as nice as possible, and yet it might be closed, see comments at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552991/technical-differences-in-creating-object-with-private-member) - two users 3k+ voted to close just because the question contained *best* (and *proper* after edit). Maybe there is something like hypersensitivity of the community or automated reaction of tired reviewers, but for some not-so-new users who read the FAQ might save the guide some time.

I'm not the greatest user, but my Q&A are not the worst trash on SO anymore. I learned it by experience and there could be other decision patterns specific for this community I am not aware of. I looked at the FAQ and about section months later since my first question, but at this point I would appreciate also a few words of actual community manners to fit in and get the best results from it.

Comment: This assumes that people read the FAQ before they even post.

Comment: @ChristopherW then it could be in the new user profile or maybe as popup window before the first post? Just searching the compromise between obtrusivity and flooding SO with bad questions.

Comment: Assumes they'll read that too. Alas, we live in a world where there will always be bad questions. We could go to individual houses, strap down first posters, and butterfly stitch their eyes open while making them preview a video of Jeff Atwood himself informing them of what a bad question is and they'll still hit the enter button because they know that one day, they'll have the off chance that someone will respond with everything they need before the tidal wave of downvotes and post flags ensue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that some people aren't even reading their own questions, let alone anything we try to tell them.

Comment: You are already warned when you try to enter a title that sounds subjective.

Comment: *"The close votes review tasks are now 50k+ and rising"* ... that in itself is not the sign of a problem. This is not something we desperately need to clean out for the sake of reducing the number.

Comment: Well, I have updated my question. It's just a thought, I will accept rejection. Just According to the comments, I have a feeling that I didn't expressed my thoughts fully before this edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are a few easy to detect patterns, that could cause an alert to the OP, informing him that the question is very likely to be closed, or refusing to submit the question.

To the given by you I would add:

- Question title has similar length to post - message that titles are not for asking questions (Facebook custom?)
- Urgent/ASAP/I need it quick - message that such information is irrelevant
- Hi, my name is... I work for... I have a dog/spider/elephant - message as above
- No question mark in body - you have forgotten a question?
- a large wall of code - a line of code is worth 100 words, no one is going to read the whole Brittanica
- but it doesn't work - message that such information is precise only when describing the employment status, not the problem with code

etc.

Comment: Would be list like this in FAQ too much work? Is it really so pointless? It would be nice to replace the "etc." for the real rest of the list.

Answer (score 5):

The close votes queue is not *really* rising. Each day, hundreds of brave reviewers brave the terrible questions and max out their review limits. It tends to fluctuate between 53-54k. Not bad.

Also, as CristopherW mentioned, very few people actually *read* the FAQ. We could try to make them scroll all the way to the bottom (just like disclaimers on website that max out the speed our scroll wheels can go). We can even give them a badge.

It doesn't matter to them. New users here are here for one thing: *I have a problem. I want an answer. JUST LET ME ASK IT!!*

Also, many users will probably 'get it' within their second-third post closed, meaning it's not that huge of a problem. If they don't, we keep closing their stuff. Then they call us bad names and leave. Problem solved.

Comment: and a few weeks before it was about 51k. There's a slow, but unstoppable rise I think.

Comment: @bwoebi However, there is also a slow, but unstoppable rise of new 3k'ers - like me and you. We have it under control.

Comment: And a slow, but unstoppable rise of new SO users who ask even more questions to be closed (or not)?

Comment: @bwoebi It will fluctuate - just like the stock market. If worst comes to worst and it gets above 100k or something, SE will step in and do *something*...

Comment: We'll discuss when the 100k ___are___ reached...

Comment: @bwoebi http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151996/215468