# Ordering algorithm to priorities close votes review

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I tried figuring out that what priority algorithm is been use to order close vote review questions, but couldn't succeed.

Any ways that's not my point, what I want to say is, shouldn't we use "maximums vote first" (on applied filter of-course)? Although it's It's a really straight forward algorithm, but I believe this will decrease the awaited question which are going to be 100K soon.

Comment: Thanks for the link shai! there's big discussion out there let me find help from it!

Comment: What do you mean "maximum vote first"? Do you mean putting the ones with the most close votes at the front of the queue?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean!

Comment: @rptwsthi wouldn't such policy cause starvation of posts? That is, posts with few votes will forever be stuck at the bottom of the queue never to be reviewed?

Comment: The close vote review queue has been discussed a few times already (with the sorting algorithm aspect touched on) (with no real resolution) - [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186817/ideas-for-the-close-queue), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145665/how-can-the-close-vote-review-queue-be-improved), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167109/close-votes-policy-review). Personally I think improving the black-box sorting algorithm isn't the most promising course of action.

Comment: Yes, that's right! I missed that point.. Thanks Again @Shai. But we must have something like that, may be something like count dependency like if we have 50 votes then 25 for max votes first and rest for as they are going, probably!